# Die wichtigsten Informationen an den Anfang des Textes

Tags: style

Salvete.

Welche Möglichkeiten gibt es, immer das wichtigste des Satzes an den Anfang vom Satz zu stellen?

Nehmen wir mal ein Beispiel aus dem Wikipedia Artikel über Donald Trump

> Trump unterstützte verschiedene politische Parteien und ist (mit kurzer Unterbrechung) seit 2009 als Republikaner registriert. Als deren Kandidat gewann er die Präsidentschaftswahl am 8. November 2016 gegen Hillary Clinton und wurde am 20. Januar 2017 US-Präsident – als erster ohne vorheriges politisches Amt oder militärischen Rang und mit dem höchsten Lebensalter bei Amtsantritt.

Umgeschrieben würde der Text so lauten:

> Verschiedene politische Parteien unterstützte Trump, registriert als
>   Republikaner ist er seit 2009 (mit einer kurzen Unterbrechung). Gegen
>   Hillary Clinton gewann er als republikanischer Kandidat die
>   Präsidentschaftswahl am 8. November 2016 - mit dem höchsten
>   Lebensalter, das jemals ein Präsidentschaftskandidat hatte, sowie als
>   erster, der noch nie ein militärisches Amt oder einen militärischen
>   Rang innehatte.

Das hört sich sehr gestottert an, gibt es elegantere Methoden diese Stilform zu benutzen?

Comment: "wichtig" ist m.E. ein sehr subjektives Kriterium. Soll es hier darum gehen, nur innerhalb eines Satzes eine Information nach vorn zu holen? Das wird in einem längeren Text schwieriger, weil Bezüge aufgebaut werden.

Comment: @Arsak ach, bei dem Narzissmus und dauerhaftem Twitter-Schreibdrang wäre es nicht verwunderlich, wenn er auch **von** ihm wäre ;)

Comment: Worte sind keine Informationen. Erst aus dem ganzen Satzgefüge ergibt sich die Information. Eine Umsortierung des Satzes kann daran nichts ändern. Die Prämisse der Frage ist schon falsch - daraus wird nichts.

Comment: @Arsak: Nee. Diesen Tipp haben ich aus der "Stilfibel".Dort steht natürlich nicht, dass man das ständig so machen soll, ich wollte es aber nur einmal ausprobieren, um zu sehen, wie weit ich das treiben kann.

Comment: Die kleine Übung aus Reiners' Stilfibel ist natürlich nicht so gemeint, dass man ganze Absätze nach dieser Masche ummodelt. Dann wird es schnell ungenießbar. Immer nur in Maßen soll man Gewürze in die Suppe rühren!

Answer (score 3):

Die Form des ersten Satzes klingt wohl durch den Passiv so holprig. Ich würde ihn folgendermaßen umformen (Wenn ich streng deiner Reihenfolge folge):

> Verschiedene politische Parteien wurden von Trump unterstützt, registriert als Republikaner ist er, mit einer kurzen Unterbrechung, seit 2009.

Der zweite Satz ist so wie er ist meiner Meinung nach in Ordnung.

Wobei Shegit Brahm sehr richtig kommentierte, dass längere Sätze Bezüge in sich aufbauen, was eine Neuordnung der Satzteile nur bedingt sinnvoll wirken lässt. Folglich sollte man sich daher fragen, ob ein solcher Aufwand wirklich notwendig ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke für so etwas ist eine Stichwortliste die beste Lösung

> Donald Trump
>
> - unterstützte verschiedene politische Parteien
> - ist seit 2009 (mit kurzen Unterbrechungen als Republikaner registriert
> - gewann als Kandidat der Republikaner gegen Hillary Clinton die Präsidentschaftswahl am 9. November 2016
> - hatte das bislang höchste Alter eines Präsidenten bei Amtsantritt
> - ist der erste Präsident ohne vorherigen militärischen Rang oder Amt

Zwar kein ausgeschriebener Text, aber setzt m.E. das geforderte am besten um.